# How do I deploy my applescript to multiple devices?

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-catalina

This is going to sound like a dumb question because I can't figure out how to word it properly. But basically I want to create a package that contains a photo and then a script to set that photo as the wallpaper for that device. This is specifically for Catalina so I am not able to modify the Desktop Photos folder. The issue that I am running into is that if I download the photo the file path is going to be attached to the user. But I can't use something like $currentuser as part of of the file path. Just hoping for any ideas at all on how to get around this. I am very new to applescript as well so probably something that I am missing. Thank you.

```
    tell current desktop
        set picture to file "/Users/lemur/Pictures/bluemoon.jpg" as POSIX file
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I haven't actually created the package yet. I am trying to figure out the best approach. I am going to try that though thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here are five two-line examples which could be helpful. Run each and inspect the result:

```
set fd to path to desktop
return fd
```

```
set fd to path to applications folder
return fd
```

```
set fd to (path to applications folder from user domain)
return fd
```

```
set fd to path to pictures folder
return fd
```

```
set fd to path to desktop pictures folder
return fd
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are talking to `System Events` anyway the syntax is pretty simple

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell current desktop
        set picture to file "bluemoon.jpg" of pictures folder
    end tell
end tell
```

`pictures folder` is always the pictures folder of the current user